# NullPointerException thrown from a returned ArrayList

Tags: java, oop

I have an ArrayList of Student from another class called Project, and I get that Array with a method called returnPreferences() but apparently it returns a null ArrayList, even though I have added objects in that ArrayList.

Really not sure what to do, I've searched for some troubleshooting but I didn't find anything useful.

```
void filterAndPrintProblem(){
   for(Project currentProject : listOfProjects){
            ArrayList<Student> listofProjectPreferences = 
   currentProject.returnPreferences();
            for(Student currentStudent : listofProjectPreferences){
                System.out.println(currentStudent.toString());
            }
   }
}


void setPreferences(Project... projects){
        if(listOfStudentPreferences != null){
            listOfStudentPreferences = new ArrayList<>();
            Collections.addAll(listOfStudentPreferences, projects);
        }
}


ArrayList<Project> returnPreferences(){
    return listOfStudentPreferences;
}
```

I want to be able to access the Objects inside the ArrayList that apparently is null.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]  THanks

Comment: You're creating a new ArrayList() only if the reference is NOT null. If you're trying to initialize it lazily, you'll want instead `if ( listOfStudentPreferences == null)` -- and then you'd want to add the projects outside the `if`.

Comment: it's exactly what @AndyThomas said, in the if statement I would need the listOfStudentPreferences be equal to null and then add the projects. I can't believe I have missed that, thank you for your time and answers.